# Хто і в який спосіб затверджує зміни до правопису української мови?

Tags: orthography, language-regulation

Я знаю, що колись (у 1999-2000) існувала [*Національна комісія з питань правопису*](http://www.radiosvoboda.org/a/24578064.html) при Кабінеті Міністрів України, але потім її розпустили.

Тим не менше, в шкільних іспитах та ЗНО час від часу змінюються та оновлюються старі правила, додаються нові (напр., де ставити наголос у слові **йогурт**, який рід має слово **тюль** тощо).

Але хто визначає ці правила, якщо комісії з питань правопису не існує?

Comment: Питання про наголос на *йогурт* вже має "своє" окреме питання:  https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/4374/260

Answer (score 9):

Комісія з питань правопису досі існує, і її склад востаннє оновлено [17 червня 2015](http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/416-2015-%D0%BF).
Щоправда, такими питаннями вона не займається. Вона працює над правописом, де затверджені основні правила мови (чинний правопис [тут](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/pravopys2015.htm))

Щодо питань наголосу й роду окремих слів слід звертатися до словників, не чув, щоб хтось міг просто проголосити оновлення роду/наголосу слова.

"Тюль" всюди бачу лише чоловічий рід... (СУМ, slovnyk.ua, https://github.com/brown-uk/dict_uk)

Ані в орфоепічному словнику Погрібного, ані в СУМ слова "йогурт" чомусь немає... Згідно з "Орфоепічним словником української мови" 2001 року наголос на "у", але я йому не дуже довіряю... А [тут](http://sum.in.ua/f/joghurt) на "о".

Щодо наголосу багатьох слів суперечки не вщухають.

**Оновлення**: щодо наголосу в слові "йогурт" [тут](http://fs4.fex.net/get/288309678216/5368933/%D0%99%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D1%82%2B%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81.pdf) можна прочитати невеличке дослідження. Висновок простий: правильний наголос "йогу́рт", усі словники, що їх видали Інститут української мови НАН України, Інститут мовознавства ім. О.О. Потебні НАН  України,  Українським  мовно-інформаційний  фонд НАН України дають лише такий наголос. Додатковий аргумент - слово турецького походження, де всі слова мають наголосна останньому складі.

Comment: От, власне, щодо слова "_йогурт_". В одному словнику наголос на "о", а в іншому - на "у". А це питання є в ЗНО. І як школяреві дізнатися, яка відповідь правильна?

Comment: Ну, хоч я й не довіряю орфоепічному словнику 2001-2003 років (можу навести купу страшних помилок), але це найновіший і виданий орфоепічний словник - рецензований і все таке. Відповідно,на ЗНО логічно користуватися ним, а не "народним словником" )

Comment: Ех, ентер надсилає коментар. Так ось, це лише моя думка, я ЗНО сам не складав, ніколи до нього не готувався, тому легко можу помилятися. Напевно, з приводу того, які відповіді на ЗНО вважаються правильними, варто створити окреме питання.

Comment: Якщо в двох словниках написано по-різному, то навряд чи "правильною" з точки зору ЗНО вважається версія, яка є в "найсвіжішому" словнику. Адже в різних словників зовсім різні ред. колегії тощо. З іншого боку, не існує якогось єдиного "офіційного словника". Але тоді виходить, що правильну відповідь до тестів ЗНО можуть знати тільки ті люди, що складали саме завдання на ЗНО?

Comment: Це дуже скидається на окреме питання, що на нього багато хто зможе відповісти значно краще за мене :) Рекомендую його й поставити окремим питанням.
Але ще раз зазначу, що другий словник - це просто хтось додав на сайті слово, тобто в нього фактично нульовий науковий статус. Орфоепічний словник 2001-2003 опубліковано, і він дає наголос "йогу́рт", хай як це для мене дивно. Раптом на ЗНО є апеляції, то на цей словник ви зможете посилатися, а на словник з сайту - точно ні.

Comment: Ну я кажу не конкретно про той словник із сайту, а просто про будь-який науковий словник, в якому є розбіжність по конкретному слову з іншими словниками

Comment: Я думаю, про наголос у слові «йогурт» варто створити окреме питання. Бо, по-перше, цікаве питання. По-друге, я, наприклад, незгоден з висновками Сергія Омельчука (хоча не маю ніякого авторитету в цьому питанні).

Comment: А тут він більше питає про те, що робити, якщо взагалі словники кажуть різне (в т.ч. якщо обидва авторитетні).

Comment: @Sasha Я пам'ятаю. Але це гарне місце, щоб зберегти цю інормацію. Крім того, пошуком "наголос йогурт" знаходиться це питання, відповідно варто тут давати якомога кращу відповідь )

Comment: Йогурт мене "сподвиг" на винесення його в окреме питання: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/4374/260

Comment: Ланка на fex не працює належним чином.

Answer (score 8):

Ця [постанова](http://zakon5.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/198-2002-%D0%BF) Кабінету Міністрів України покладає на Міністерство освіти і науки та Національну академію наук забезпечення діяльності Української національної комісії з питань правопису та видання "Українського правопису.

Ця [постанова](http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/416-2015-%D0%BF) Кабінету Міністрів України визначає склад Української національної комісії з питань правопису на 2015 рік.

Отже, відповідна комісія існує та має чинний склад, затверджений у 2015 році.