# Чи змінилися правила запису транскрипції, що вчать у школі, за останні 10 років?

Tags: фонетика

Дивна річ - зараз в школах вчать не таку транскрипцію, як років ~10 тому.

Візьмемо до прикладу слово **байдужість**.
Як зробив би транскрипцію я:

байдужість - `[б а й' д у ж' і с т']`

Як вона ж подається у різноманітних посібниках:

байдужість - `[б а ĭ д у' ж’ і с´ т´]`

---

За пошуком в Ґуґлі "транскрипція слова байдужість" можна знайти обидва варіанти. Наприклад, другий варіант знаходиться в "Навчальний посібник для підготовки до ЗНО для слухачів системи довузівської підготовки Харків Видавництво НУА 2010".

Схоже, що другий варіант є новішим, я такого зі школи не пам’ятаю, всі знайомі, кого запитував, теж. Серед них — вчителька укр. мови на пенсії.

- Звук "*й*" сам по собі не потребує, щоб його розкладали на окремі звуки.
- У вимові я не чув ба**і**дужість, сам вимовляю ба**й**дужість, з чітким `й`, таким, що можна було б апострофа поставити.

Таке враження, що хтось цілеспрямовано ускладнює правила мови.

*І, в якості додаткового питання: хто в сучасній Україні визначає правила мови?*

Comment: Схоже, що про транскрипцію в вас дуже розпливчасте уявлення. Де там у вас наголос? Хто ж ставить знак м’якости після [й] (чи це наголос?), цей звук і так _завжди_ м’який. [ĭ] це не просто [i], це нескладове [i], тобто саме Й. І хіба ви вимовляєте _байдужість_ із твердим [c]? У другому варіянті транскрипції все правильно. Але дійсно, транскрипція змінилася з часом, в усьому світі, та тільки не в нас, писати транскрипцію кирилкою – це смішно, решта світу для цього використовує [міжнародний фонетичний алфавіт](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Міжнародний_фонетичний_алфавіт).

Comment: Ласкаво просимо на сайт Ukrainian.SE! Давайте, спробуємо сформулювати так, щоб було одне і конкретне запитання. Бо якщо запитання про вимову цього слова — це одне, а якщо «хто визначає правила мови?», то [tag:language-regulation], але тоді не дуже зрозуміло, до чого цей приклад.

Comment: Й зі знаком м’якості скопіпастив не думаючи, тут ви праві, і С мабуть таки м’яке. Але раніше ж не було нескладових і, чи я помиляюсь? Навіщо ускладнювати граматику на пустому місці? 

Дійсно краще вже по стандарту записувати за допомогою МФА, щоб не було суперечностей.

Comment: bytebuster, про «хто визначає правила мови?» це якби податкове питання. Дякую що відповіли на нього, думаю що ця відповідь буде корисна тут. Кожен хто цікавиться перейде на суміжну тему і прочитає бульше.

Comment: @TheKitMurkit, я маю на увазі, що варто відредагувати цей допис  і чітко сформулювати одне запитання. Ви можете це зробити, натиснувши [edit]. Окремо від того, коли звертаєтеся до когось у коментарі, пишіть "@" і потім username (буде підказка). Лише у цьому випадку надійде повідомлення тому, до кого звертаєтеся.

Comment: Про те хто визначає правила мови було тут: [Хто і в який спосіб затверджує зміни до правопису української мови?](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/16/69)

Comment: TheKitMurkit, я думаю, це просто різні системи транскрипції і різні рівні деталізації. Навіть у МФА одне й те саме слово певної мови можна передавати по-різному: як послідовність фонем (наприклад, /d/) і показуючи конкретні нюанси звучання (наприклад, [d̪]). На шкільному рівні, мені здається, обидві надані Вами транскрипції *приблизно* вірні — хоча друга точніша (показує наголос над *у* та пом'якшене *с*). При цьому друга використовує незвичне для Вас позначення звуку *й* (ĭ). Я думаю, це не «*й* розкладається» і «*й* звучить як *і*», а це просто інше позначення. …

Comment: … Не знаю чи помітили Ви, але там не просто «*і* з крапкою», там [окремий спеціальний знак](http://graphemica.com/%C4%AD). Чи є якась користь від використання мудрованих знаків, якщо інші звуки все одно позначаються звичайною кирилицею, я не знаю — це треба конкретний підручник дивитися, щоб зрозуміти. У Вам немає часом посилання?

Comment: @Sasha Є посилання на посібник https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=16&ved=0ahUKEwjpm_Xb4sTSAhUlD5oKHRIWCrY4ChAWCDkwBQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nua.kharkov.ua%2Feng%2Fimages%2Fstories%2FKafedri%2FKaf_Ukrainovedenya%2Fmetod_obespechenie%2FBerest_Met_pos_ZNO_FDP.doc&usg=AFQjCNFLB3n0RO0Z1cc1YRR783h9VSoOSw&sig2=TguVq6hMWx6MrlKXcl2LJg&bvm=bv.148747831,d.bGg

Comment: @TheKitMurkit, схоже на банальний одрук. У правилах вище (ст. 5–7) ніде не згадується, що звук від *й* має позначатися *[ĭ]* — навпаки, він позначається *[й]*.

Comment: @TheKitMurkit, окрім того в очі кидається неякісність типографіки. На сторінці 5 сказано, що наголос і м'якість позначаються [вертикальним апострофом](http://graphemica.com/'), а пом'якшеність — [типографським](http://graphemica.com/’). На сторінці ж 12 (з Вашим прикладом): у них наголос і пом'якшеність позначаються таки як сказано, але м'якість — [акутом](http://graphemica.com/´) (а не як сказано на ст. 5). При цьому на сторінці 5 узагалі сказано, що наголос має бути *над* голосним, але в жодному прикладі (навіть на ст. 5) такого нема. Коротше — видна неякісність, тому одруки ймовірні.

Comment: @TheKitMurkit, крім того, Ви врахуйте, що те, що на ст. 12 — не лише правильні транскрипції — там лише *одна* правильна транскрипція на кожен рядок. Але, так, я думаю, що вони мали на увазі правильним таки *A* — `[байду'ж’іс´т´]`. Але просто через одрук замість `[байду'ж’іс´т´]` — `[баĭду'ж’іс´т´]`.

Comment: Ось Вам [інший підручник підготовки до ЗНО](http://zno.academia.in.ua/mod/book/view.php?id=1357&chapterid=80) — просто щоби дивитися різні джерела.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильна транскрипція слова *байдужість* згідно з сучасними методичками підготовки до ЗНО:

> [б а й д у́ ж' і с´ т´] <sub>(або ще [б а j д у́ ж' і с´ т´])</sub>

- Приголосний звук від літери *й* позначається як [й] або [j] (мала латинська *J*). У навчальному посібнику «Українська мова» (2010, Харків, НУА), в який Ви дивилися — на 12-й сторінці одрук (помилково інший знак). М'якість звуку від [й] позначати не треба, бо він завжди м'який.
- Голосний звук від літери *у* в даному випадку наголошений. Наголошеність позначається скісною рискою (  ́ ) над відповідним знаком або після нього. У тому ж посібнику рекомендують *над*, але самі же своїй рекомендації не слідують.
- Приголосний звук від літери *ж* у даному випадку пом'якшений. Не твердий він тому, що після нього йде [і] (один із голосних звуків, що завжди роблять попередній приголосний м'яким або пом'якшеним), а не повністю м'який він тому, що [ж] в українській мові ніколи не буває повністю м'яким (м'якими можуть бути лише «*д*е *т*и *з*'ї*с*и *ц*і *л*и*н*и»).
- Приголосні звуки від літер *с* і *т* у даному випадку м'які. Те, що м'який знак після *т* робить відповідний приголосний звук м'яким — очевидно. В який випадках він робить м'яким і попередній приголосний звук — я точно й не знаю (припускаю, що тоді, коли обидві голосні належать до тих, що можуть бути м'якими — [дтзсцлн]; так відбувається не лише при м'якому знаку, а й при будь-яких голосних, що пом'якшують, наприклад, [с´ т´ і л]).

Конкретно в цій відповіді я позначаю м'який приголосний скісною рискою (с´), а пом'якшений — вертикальною (ж'). Наскільки це загальноприйняті позначення і наскільки в цій сфері взагалі можуть бути загальноприйняті позначення — я не знаю. Припускаю, що випускників на ЗНО не будуть мордувати через «не таку риску» — але якщо незнання різниці між м'якими і пом'якшеними призведе до подальших помилок (<s>[без**'**б'уд͡же́тний]</s>[безб'уд͡же́тний]) — то це вже, мабуть, буде мінус бал.

---

Не думаю, що щось суттєво змінилося від того, що було десять років тому. Я сам приблизно тоді й навчався. Могли почати детальніше розглядати; те, що тоді вивчали якось поверхнево, зараз можуть розбирати глибше. (Наприклад, я пам'ятаю, як вчителька розповідала про різницю між м'якими і пом'якшеними — але мені особисто здалося, що те були радше додаткові матеріали — принаймні я їх так тоді сприймав.)

---

Фактично: мова — це те, як розмовляють люди.

Юридично: норми української мови як державної встановлюються Міністерством освіти і науки через офіційний правопис та словники.

Але конвенції транскрибування, мені здається, мало стосуються норм мови як такої (бо як не транскрибуй — на кожну транскрипцію теоретично можна зробити ще точнішу; тобто, по-моєму, це питання радше домовленностей і того, наскільки певна транскрипція правильна *в межах конкретних домовленостей* — а не взагалі).

---

Update: Kyrylo Yatsenko підказує, що транскрипційний знак [ĭ] (як і [ў]; тобто `ı` та `у` з бревісом як над `й`) все ж може застосовуватися в українських транскрипціях (для позначення звуків від *й* та *в* перед наступним приголосним, наприклад, [наĭдо́ўший]). Але це явно не рівень ЗНО; в даному випадку це одрук (помилка авторів посібника). Можливо, вони скопіювали транскрипцію слова *байдужість* з іншої своєї книги (для іншої аудиторії).

Comment: +1, але зробити такий одрук вкрай складно :)
"Сучасна українська мова Фонетика. Фонологія. Орфоепія. Графіка" видавництва "Академія" 2010го року стверджує, що літера "й" позначає фонему /і/ з алофоном [ĭ] (сторінка 146) перед приголосними й наприкінці слова.
Також цей символ використовує Погрібний в орфоепічному словнику.
Пара й-ĭ змінюється за тими ж правилами, що й в-ў.
Але в багатьох транскрипціях цю різницю не вказують, і просто пишуть "й", хоча "ў" всюди, де я бачив, вказують.
Ми вже з YellowSky про це довго сперечалися в іншому питанні...

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, так а Ви подивіться [той самий посібник](http://www.nua.kharkov.ua/eng/images/stories/Kafedri/Kaf_Ukrainovedenya/metod_obespechenie/Berest_Met_pos_ZNO_FDP.doc) — там ніде більше знак «ĭ» не згадується (а «ў» взагалі). [В іншому посібнику до ЗНО](http://zno.academia.in.ua/mod/book/view.php?id=1357&chapterid=80) є приклад *[йак парос´т´ винограднойі лози | плеᵘка**й**теᵘ мову | пи'л´но й неᵘнастан:о пол´і'т´ бурйа'н]*. Тобто я не кажу, що «ĭ» невірно, але «ĭ» і «ў» не для ЗНО. Я думаю, вони просто скопіпастили *[баĭду'ж’іс´т´]* з іншого свого підручника (вищого рівня).

Comment: я розумію, що помилка, і теж гадаю, що просто копіпаст. Але "одрук" для мене - це коли випадково помилився символом при наборі з клавіатури, наприклад, а не коли скопіював з іншого джерела й не оновив формат. Як це стисло передати у вашій відповіді гадки не маю, просто від відповіді складається враження, ніби знак "ĭ" це взагалі помилка й він ніколи не використовується. Хотів коментарем виправити це враження. )

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, чи вписуються в поняття «одрук» помилки друкарів, більші за пропустив літеру (наприклад: пропустив рядок, пропустив сторінку, не те джерело) — то окреме питання. Я, думаючи над [оцим](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/682/4), спершу був думав, що «друкарська помилка», «одрук» і «друкарський чортик» — то різні речі, бо: «друкарська помилка» і «друкарський чортик» у широкому сенсі, мабуть, можуть позначати будь-яку помилку друкаря (навіть дуже значну), а «одрук» — це винятково «промазав мимо клавіші». Але потім засумнівався, здалося, що всі три можуть будь-яку помилку.