# Наголос у слові “йогурт”

Tags: наголос

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/f/joghurt) дає наголос на перший склад: йо́гурт. Так само дає сайт [Словники України online](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/):

> [image: йогурт наголос, по версії "Словники України online"]

Існує [альтернативна думка](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/21/260):

> Висновок простий: правильний наголос "йогу́рт", усі словники, що їх
>   видали Інститут української мови НАН України, Інститут мовознавства
>   ім. О.О. Потебні НАН України, Українським мовно-інформаційний фонд НАН
>   України дають лише такий наголос. Додатковий аргумент - слово
>   турецького походження, де всі слова мають наголос на останньому складі.

В коментарях згадують ще "Орфоепічний словник української мови в двох томах: Близько 140 000 слів" (Київ: Довiра, 2001 та 2003, ISBN: 9665071092, 9665071165), який теж "за" наголос на 2-му складі.

Словник **Складні випадки наголошення : словник-довідник / С. І. Головащук. – Київ: Либідь, 1995. – 191 с.** не вважає *йогурт* складним випадком :-).

То де ж Pravduh?

Comment: «"йогу́рт", усі словники, що їх видали …, Інститут мовознавства ім. О.О. Потебні НАН України, … дають лише такий наголос» — мушу зауважити конкретно до цього, бо принаймні орфографічний словник за ред. Скляренка з грифом Інституту (2008) каже йо́гурт.

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT]: не все так однозначно з вимовою наголосу в турецькій мові (див. нижче).

TL;DR:

- **йогу́рт** - правильно, бо так в турецькій, а з неї ми завжди запозичуємо зі збереженням наголосу на останньому складі.
- **йо́гурт** - прикре непорозуміння в "неавторитетних джерелах", які підхопили "сучасні засоби масової інформації", які наразі не виконують функції пропагування культури усного мовлення.

---

В статті [Сергій ОМЕЛЬЧУК, доктор педагогічних наук, доцент. Йогу́рт чи йо́гурт? До питання про нормативність наголошення запозичених слів в
українській мові](http://ekhsuir.kspu.edu/bitstream/123456789/852/1/%D0%99%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D1%82%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81.pdf) стверджуться:

> Як  засвідчують  лексикографічні  джерела [8, 9], слово *йогу́рт* є
> запозиченим і походить від турецького *yogurt*, що позначає пастоподібний
> кисломолочний напій зі сквашеного особливим чином молока, як правило, із
> фруктовими додатками (домішками).
>
> ...
>
> Зауважимо, що фіксований (закріплений) на останньому складі наголос є
> однією з основних акцентуаційних особливостей сучасної турецької мови...

Тоді в тексті є посилання на "авторитетні лексикографічні джерела":

> Отже, авторитетні лексикографічні джерела, видані в другій половині
> ХХ – на початку ХХІ століття, засвідчують, що українській мові ніколи не
> було властиве наголошення лексеми *йогу́рт* на першому складі.

І далі по тексту про походження альтернативного наголосу:

> Проте  укладачі,  наприклад,  Великого  тлумачного  словника  сучасної
> української  мови (за  редакцією  В.Т. Бусела) подають  слово *йогурт*
> із порушенням  акцентуаційних  норм – з  наголосом  на  першому
> складі [2, с. 510], а слово *югурт* – правильно (з наголосом на останньому):
> **югу́рт**, -у, ч. Те саме, що **йо́гурт** [2, с. 1643].

---

[EDIT]: На сайті forvo.com можна почути [різну вимову yogurt турецькою](https://forvo.com/word/yo%C4%9Furt/), 3/4 дають наголос на першому складі, 1/4 (з південної провінції) - на останньому. Вимова (наголоси) в турецькій мові - [питання](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_phonology#Stress_or_pitch?) [непросте](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-turkish-stress.1108129/).

На сайті dictionary.cambridge.org можна почути [вимову yogurt Британською та Американською англійськими](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/yogurt), а саме в обох варіантах на першому складі. Чому в англійській так? Спроба виясняти це є в [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/450909/303806).

Існує імовірність що українські медіа запозичили наголос з медіа американських (наприклад, при перекладі реклами йогурту).

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Думки</sup>

**Зауваження.** Осідок *sum.in.ua* справді позначає ся як *словник української мови*, а саме *в 11 книгах*, і тримає його як основного, але ланка чітко вказує на *новітнього онлайнового словника української мови (2013—2018)*. Це також означає, що згаданий основний словник його не має. Про це також окремо згадують уступом раніше в згаданої вами [иншеможливої думки](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/21/260):

> Ані в орфоепічному словнику Погрібного, ані в СУМ слова *йогурт* чомусь немає…

Однак, новіший *словник української мови в 20 книгах* вже [має](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=181802) слова з наголосом на **о**.

---

**Походження.** Скористаймо *етимолоґічним словником української мови*. Замість *йогурт* [маємо](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom2.pdf#page=326) *йо́ґурт*, котре [ся відсилає](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom6.pdf#page=519) до *югу́рт*:

> «кисломолочний продукт», *йо́ґурт* «те саме»;
>
> російська *йо́гурт*, польська, чеська jogurt, болгарська *йо́гу́рт* «те саме»;
>
> недавнє запозичення, можливо, за посередництвом російської мови з тюркських, порівняйте: турецька yoğurt «те саме»
>
> Kopaliński 457; Holub—Lyer 224; БЕР 2 104;

---

**Розбір** отриманого.

Нове запозичення ([старі словники](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D1%82&highlight=on) не мають) з московської мови, котра запозичила з якоїсь [тюрської мови](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8), не обовʼязково з турецької. Цілком можливо, що навіть взагалі не з тюрської, а з анґлійської *yogurt* (инше можливе *youghurt*), котре [звучить](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/yogurt) з наголосом на перший склад і зі звуком **ґ**, як і [московською](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D1%82&all=x). Словопоходження ясне:

> 1620s, a mispronunciation of Turkish *yogurt*, in which the *-g-* is a "soft" sound, in many dialects closer to an English "w." The root *yog* means roughly "to condense" and is related to yogun "intense," *yogush* "liquify" (of water vapor), *yogur* "knead."

Цей уступ може додати вагу до моєї думки, що московська могла запозичити з анґлійської чи з иншої західної мови. Згадані [чеська](//cs.wiktionary.org/wiki/jogurt) та [польська](//pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/jogurt) мають ту саму вимову та наголос (для другої це також зручно, оскільки [має сталого наголосу](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F#%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81) на передостанній склад). *Великий словник польської мови* [вказує](http://wsjp.pl/do_druku.php?id_hasla=20825&id_znaczenia=2449542) на перший запис в польському словнику 1958—69 роках під редактурою [Дорошевского](//pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witold_Doroszewski), також походження від німецької *yoghurt* та французької *yoghourt*. [Німецька](//de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Joghurt) досі має схожу вимову, а ось з французькою цікавіше: схоже, вона теж мала (і [має](//fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaourt#cite_note-1) для инших франкомовних реґіонів, як Канада, Бельґія та Швайц; инші записи: *yahourt*, *yogourt*) таку вимову, а наразі вона переважно пише ся як [*yaourt*](//fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/yaourt), вимовляє ся як *я́ур(т)* ([румунською](//ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iaurt) теж щось подібно, можливе пряме запозичення з французької), наголос наче [ся зберіг](http://wordreference.com/fren/reverse/yaourt); теж вказує ся на запозичення з турецької:

> (*XV<sup>e</sup> siècle*) Du turc ottoman یوغورت, *yōghurt*, *yoğurt* (turc moderne *yoğurt*) apparenté à *yoğurtmak* (« épaissir »)..

---

**Перезапозичення.** Отже братимо за основу турецьку мову: наголос, [справді](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yo%C4%9Furt#Turkish), **на другий склад**.

Але на цьому я б не зупинив ся. Маю декілька уточнень, **ğ** зазвичай ся не вимовляє (инколи може бути звуком [*w*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_labio-velar_approximant), котрою буває українська **в**), тому матимемо: *йоу́рт* або *йову́рт*. Питому українська не дуже любить дві голосні поспіль, тому другий спосіб ліпший.

Про всяк, я знов звернув увагу на **ğ**. [Вікі](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%9E) вказує, що звичаєвим звуком (не тільки турецької, а скільки для тюрських мов) для неї є [*ɣ*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_velar_fricative) [дзвінкий мʼяко-піднебінний (задньопіднебінний, велярний) фрикативний], котрого українська не має (але [білоруська](//be.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%90%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%8B%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), схоже, так і як **г**), але, схоже, **г** відносно близька, тому можна і *йогу́рт*.

Також цікаво, що *югурт* теж має право на існування, оскільки [існував](//tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo%C4%9Furt#Adland%C4%B1rma) запис *yuğurt*. Як і *я(г)урт* через [кипчаську](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kipchak_language) мову.

Answer (score -3):

Йогурт має наголос на першому складі, бо так його вимовляють усі.

Всі інші аргументи не мають ніякого значення, адже мова - це жива річ, яка розвивається в народі, незалежно від того, який наголос хочуть поставити на слові науковці.

Науковці мають менше дивитись на турецькі джерела, і більше слідкувати за тим, що відбувається в українському мовному середовищі, занотовувати і фіксувати зміни, а не намагатися насадити неприродні для мовців правила.

Comment: -1: Re: *бо так його вимовляють усі* — ні, не усі. Мій сусід вимовляє не так, значить, цей допис містить неправдиву інформацію, і усі подальші роздуми, дійсно, *не мають ніякого значення*, бо ґрунтуються на неправдивій тезі. Якщо автор бажає обговорювати числове співвідношення тих, хто вимовляє «так» і «не так», то варто надати **посилання на авторитетні джерела**, де є числові значення.