# Мова граматика етимологія походження

Tags: етимологія, граматика, фонетика

Як і хто змінює українську мову під впливом інших країн?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Хто і в який спосіб затверджує зміни до правопису української мови?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/16/%d0%a5%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%96-%d0%b2-%d1%8f%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%96%d0%b1-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%94-%d0%b7%d0%bc%d1%96%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%83-%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%97%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%97-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8)

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до спільности Ukrainian Language.SE! Ваше запитання виглядає занадто загальним. Унаслідок цього, відповідь може займати цілі книги. Такі запитання не дуже підходять на цьому сайті. По-друге, у контексті етимології/походження, незрозуміло, що означає «зміни». Етимологія кожного слова незмінна, її легко дослідити у словниках. По-третє, варто розкрити «під впливом інших країн». Що ви розумієте під цим? Приклади? По-четверте, досить часто запитання конкретизується, коли його автор вказує, які **попередні дослідження** він/вона зробив у спробі самостійно знайти відповідь.

Comment: У моєму розумінні — мову має формувати народ. Тобто мова — це те, як реально кажуть (узус). А різні наукові організації мають у першу чергу досліджувати цей процес (дескриптивне мовознавство), а не намагатися впливати на нього (прескриптивне мовознавство). Але це суто мій погляд, інші люди можуть вважати по-іншому.

Comment: This question should be closed as a duplicate.